# How do I synchronize master and origin/master using egit in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I created a local git repository, and I push changes from it to a gitosis remote that I created with

```
git init my_git
git remote add origin git@server:my_git
... various adds and commits
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

Now, I edit and commit changes locally in eclipse, and when I commit, I see (using qgit) that it moves my `master` branch to that version.

However, it also shows me that `origin/master` is at the previous version.

`git status` on command line shows me everything is up to date:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I can see the differences in versions with

```
git diff origin/master
```

If i do `git push` on my command line, then qgit shows me the `origin/master` branch is now at same place as my `master`.

I can't work out how to configure the "remote / push" or "remote / configure push to upstream" dialog in eclipse to do the same thing as a command line `git push` to move the `origin/master` to the same level as the `master`.

I always have to do the command line push to make the `origin/master` come up to the same place as `master`.

Q1. Can anyone tell me how to do this in eclipse?

Q2. What is the command line version of `git push` doing that the eclipse version doesn't do?

Q3. Are my assumptions that `master` is my local HEAD pointer and `origin/master` is the remote server's view of the current HEAD correct?

Comment: Is the `master` branch in the gitolite repository updated when you push from Eclipse, though?

Comment: yes, it appears it is updated. i did a push from eclipse, and then cloned the gitolite repository elsewhere and the changes i made are in my new clone. the `origin/master` is still set at the previous version, so that tells me the push is working and `origin/master` isn't the remote server's HEAD. The new clone has "master", "origin/master" on the latest verison, but also a "origin/origin/master" at the previous version

Comment: That you've got an `origin/origin/master` in the new clone suggests to me that you've somehow accidentally pushed `origin/master` (rather than just `master`) to a matching name in the gitolite repository.

Comment: Thanks, it appears I had done that, and i've now removed the remote origin/origin/master, and edited my push to only do `master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the relevant part of [egit's documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream) you can either:

- click the "Add all branches spec" button, to push all of your local branches to ones with the same name in the remote repository, or
- (the much safer option) just select `master` under both "Source ref" and "Destination ref" to only push your `master` branch

The remote-tracking branch `origin/master` is usually updated by `git fetch` (which is part of what `git pull` does), but with command line git, the remote-tracking branch is *also* updated on a successful push to the branch in the remote repository that's being tracked.  It's possible that Egit, being based one of the pure Java implementations of git, [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/), rather than the command-line tools, doesn't update `origin/master` on a successful push in the same way.  If that's the case, you can just [do a fetch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories) to update `origin/master`.

---

*Update*: It seems that this is a known bug in EGit (not the underlying JGit) - the bug report is here:

- [Push does not update remote tracking branch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317411)

Comment: Excellent, the fetch did the trick. I think I understand why I have to fetch locally move the `origin/master` now, would this be a feature or a bug? I'd have expected to locally know where the remote master is if i was the one who just pushed a change to it, the fact i have to ask for it in a second step seems odd, and the command line is doing what I'd more naturally expect to happen.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect the same, and I would call it a bug.  In fact, I've just found this in the bug tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317411

Answer (score 1):

An update to this, I was using eclipse Helios, and I've upgraded to Indigo, with the latest version of egit, and the fix appears to be active, as I'm no longer having to pull after a push.

Comment: Hmm, I use Kepler and have local repo "L1" and also remote bare repo "R1" on another disk partition. Besides I made a bare clone "P" of R on a pendrive. On another computer I made a clone "R2" of P and then checkout out project form R2 into Eclipse using repo "L2". It basically server to exchange changes between two computers with help of pendrive and having bare backups on both computers. It looks like this: